# How to interpret "crankshaft adaptation inlet Grad KW" value?

Tags: bmw, valve, camshaft, intake, angle

I'm trying to understand the meaning of this value and the implications of it being over the 120 limit.

Do you think you could help me out with some thoughts about it?

I think it should say "camshaft" instead of "crankshaft", since that is the intake camshaft.

The engine is the BMW's N42B20A, the infamous 2.0 liter petrol, naturally aspirated, with VANOS and Valvetronic.

This would be a VANOS presentation in case you are not familiar with this system: https://www.bimmerfest.com/attachments/bmw_product_info_vanos_training_class-pdf.498656

[image]

Edit 1: Added photo with my engine a bit warmer:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Two things. Not sure if this is directly out of the training, if so I can't explain the value itself. If this is something which you are doing with your own Bimmer, you'd want to ensure the vehicle is fully up to temperature before interpreting any values expressed (ie: the high value). Secondly, in quite a few things, even though it's the camshaft, the values represented have to do with degrees of crankshaft rotation.  This may be the case here (and why it shows "Crankshaft" in the title).

Comment: Thank you @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2! Luckily, I had a recent recording of INPA with engine warmed up. Indeed, it's my own car, I'm trying to understand what information can I get from that parameter. I've seen that people have that value very close to 120, but below it.

Comment: If that is "engine fully warmed" and it is truly Fahrenheit shown (upper right), then you're either not as fully warmed up as you think you are, or there's a huge issue your thermostat/cooling system. 85°F is NOWHERE near operating temperature. Even in Celsius, this would be low just not quite as bad (Celcius should most likely be around 100°, maybe a few degrees higher).

Comment: And so you know ... I rebuilt the VANOS in my son's BMW 330Ci last year. I'm familiar with the system, but not familiar with the software you're showing here.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2, I understand. I don't have one with the engine at its top running temperature, right now. The second picture was after driving 50 km's and possibly 20-30 minutes of it sitting turned off. But I recall the temperature gauge in the dashboard being close to the middle. The shown software is called INPA, it is factory BMW diagnostics software, an ancestor of ISTA.

Comment: I haven't looked at any of them, but one or more of the videos listed in this Google search may help you: https://www.google.com/search?q=understanding+BMW+INPA+data

Comment: In essence, you're viewing variable camshaft timing at idle rpm. Without a load, timing should be neutral, whatever its assigned value. Timing should change as rpm and loads changes. Are there values given in your database? Service manuals? Reviewing the pdf shows the graph where timing starts at 120 then retards for intake and advances for exhaust camshafts.

Comment: @FDryer I wish I could find a service manual for this engine. I looked for one many times, but I did not find one.

Comment: As a member in vehicle forum, I was given access to Mitchell data for online to almost every vehicle service manual. Even a pirated copy of electronic service manuals for GM existed for anyone willing to search online. Alldata.diy is another online subscription service for access to factory service manuals. There may be others but these two stand out in my mind and recommended to anyone needing specific info that was always available in hard copy.

Comment: @FDryer which vehicle forum?

Comment: A search using your info shows at least one BMW forum; https://www.bimmerfest.com/threads/valvetronic-motor-calibration.1017945/. Another; https://www.bmw-driver.net/. Some info about N42B20 engines; https://www.motorreviewer.com/engine.php?engine_id=66.